# Alter a MySQL column to be AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: sql, mysql, alter-table

I’m trying to modify a table to make its primary key column `AUTO_INCREMENT` after the fact.  I have tried the following SQL, but got a syntax error notification.

```sql
ALTER TABLE document
ALTER COLUMN document_id AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

```
+--------------------+
| VERSION()          |
+--------------------+
| 5.0.75-0ubuntu10.2 |
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 459, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT auto_increment
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would suggest INT(4).  Any particular reason?

Comment: @Steven Oxley because I declared my table that way.

Comment: Specifying a number between parenthesis does exactly *nothing* (well ok, almost nothing) for MySQL integer types. The only thing that may be influenced by the number is the display width, and it is up to the client to do that. But don't be deceived and think that it works like it does for VARCHAR and DECIMAL types - in those cases, the amount of data you can store in there is actually specified, whereas a particular flavour of INT is always allows storage of the exact same range of values

Comment: I always get an primary key error while doing this operations, so I have this is what I do:

    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
    ALTER TABLE document DROP PRIMARY KEY;
    ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT PRIMARY KEY 
    AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in MySQL because you need to set the column as a primary key since only one column is allowed to be auto_increment (also see [Roland Bouman's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169099/1440546)

Answer (score 91):

Roman is right, but note that the auto_increment column must be part of the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY (and in almost 100% of the cases, it should be the only column that makes up the PRIMARY KEY):

```
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY document_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: +1. Primary key required if not defined at the time of table creation.

Comment: Also this means that data in that column needs to be already unique

Answer (score 13):

In my case it only worked when I put `not null`. I think this is a constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can apply the atuto_increment constraint to the data column by the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY COLUMN customer_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

But, if the columns are part of a foreign key constraint you, will most probably receive an error. Therefore, it is advised to turn off foreign_key_checks by using the following query:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

Therefore, use the following query instead:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY COLUMN customer_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In real-life situations the PK is very likely to be part of a FK constraint.

Answer (score 8):

You must specify the type of the column before the `auto_increment` directive, i.e. `ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: It should be `MODIFY COLUMN`

Answer (score 8):

The SQL to do this would be:

```
ALTER TABLE `document` MODIFY COLUMN `document_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

There are a couple of reasons that your SQL might not work.  First, you must re-specify the data type (`INT` in this case).  Also, the column you are trying to alter must be indexed (it does not have to be the primary key, but usually that is what you would want).  Furthermore, there can only be one `AUTO_INCREMENT` column for each table.  So, you may wish to run the following SQL (if your column is not indexed):

```
ALTER TABLE `document` MODIFY `document_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

You can find more information in the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html for the modify column syntax and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html for more information about specifying columns.

Answer (score 7):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is part of the column's datatype, you have to define the complete datatype for the column again:

```
ALTER TABLE document
ALTER COLUMN document_id int AUTO_INCREMENT
```

(`int` taken as an example, you should set it to the type the column had before)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
 alter table [table_name] modify column [column_name] [column_type] AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: This seems to be just a repeat of all the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Below statement works. Note that you need to mention the data type again for the column name (redeclare the data type the column was before).

```
ALTER TABLE document
MODIFY COLUMN document_id int AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following query to make document_id to increment automatically

```
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT auto_increment
```

It is preferred to make document_id primary key as well

```
ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: Note that if that column is already a primary key you can't declare it again there else it gives error about multiple primary keys (you'd expect it to be a bit more clever there and see that it's the same primary key I guess). So in that case you just skip the PRIMARY KEY and it doesn't affect the existing primary key setting on that column

Answer (score 4):

### Setting column as primary key and auto_increment at the same time:

```
  mysql> ALTER TABLE persons MODIFY COLUMN personID INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY;
    Query OK, 10 rows affected (0.77 sec)
    Records: 10  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

    mysql>
```

Answer (score 3):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` is part of the column's datatype, you have to define the complete datatype for the column again:

```
ALTER TABLE document
MODIFY COLUMN document_id int AUTO_INCREMENT
```

(int taken as an example, you should set it to the type the column had before)

Answer (score 3):

If none of  the above works try this. This is what I did in MYSQL and yes, you need to write the column name (document_id) twice.

```
ALTER TABLE document
CHANGE COLUMN document_id document_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Answer (score 2):

To modify the column  in mysql we use alter and modify keywords. Suppose we have created a table like:

```
create table emp(
    id varchar(20),
    ename varchar(20),
    salary float
);
```

Now we want to modify type of the column id to integer with auto increment. You could do this with a command like:

```
alter table emp modify column id int(10) auto_increment;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table tbl_user MODIFY COLUMN id int(10) auto_increment;
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous Table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE apim_log_request (TransactionId varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL);
```

For changing the TransactionId to auto increment use this query

```
ALTER TABLE apim_log_request MODIFY COLUMN TransactionId INT auto_increment;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like this:

`alter table document modify column id int(11) auto_increment;`

Answer (score 1):

As you are redefining the column again, you have to specify the datatype again and add auto_increment to it as it's a part of datatype.

```
ALTER TABLE `document` MODIFY COLUMN `document_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN id datatype auto_increment;
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `SQL` tag is attached to the question I really think all answers missed one major point.

**`MODIFY` command does not exist in SQL server** So you will be getting an error when you run the

`ALTER TABLE Satellites MODIFY COLUMN SatelliteID INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY;`

[image]

In this case you can either add new column as `INT IDENTITY`

```
ALTER TABLE Satellites
   ADD ID INT IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED;
```

#### OR

Fill the existing null index with incremental numbers using this method,

```
DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE Satellites SET @id = SatelliteID = @id + 1
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the following queries:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN IDCol

ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD IDCol INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```