# Add auto_increment to primary key in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have table named A with column B defined  `int not null Primary Key` and there are 4-5 foreign keys that point to this column already. With what syntax of `Alter` to make this primary key column be AUTO_INCREMENT ?

Comment: you asked just once faced task? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/mysql-alter-a-column-to-be-auto-increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE A AUTO_INCREMENT=1`

Answer (score 1):

Hi does something like this work?

```
alter table A B int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I believe you should use something similar, if you use SQLYog to do it with the user interface then you see in the history tab the corresponding alter command generated.

Comment: Ultor is right, see the proper solution in the question he has posted above.

Answer (score 1):

If its a primary column go to the table defination, there u can set the auto increment value in the column properties. 
go to the Column Properties ----> click on identity Specification -----> give the identity increment value and the identity seed value. then for every new row the value will be auto incremented.