# How to get MySQL value from certain row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 5 rows. Every time a user enters data into a form, it is entered into the table. My first column is called `id` and holds the number of the post. What I want to do is get the value of `id` from the previous row, add one to it and set it as the value in  the current post's `id` field. How do I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: Why not use auto-increment?

Comment: @lc. didn't know it existed. mysql noob here :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set that field as `primary key` and `auto-increment`, it will automatically do this for you. You won't have to `fetch the previous row` and `add` that `field value` to next one.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query you need is:

```
SELECT max(id) 
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: Yeah, and @Dead Man's answer will obviously help you out too :)

Answer (score 2):

Set attribute `auto increment` for "ID" field in the table that contains 5 columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sql query like

```
"INSERT INTO my_table (id auto_increment,primary key(id))";
```

then you can get...

and eachtime you need not worry to insert id ,it will automatically increments

Answer (score 1):

I would not recomend doing this as it could lead to a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Change the table structure and set the `id` field to be the `primary key` and set it to `auto increment`.  This way anytime a new row is added, it will auto-magically be assigned the next ID.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/mysql-alter-a-column-to-be-auto-increment) on details of how to set auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

here is the query to alter your table and it will set your field or column as primary key and also auto increment it.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```