# WP not giving an ID in my wp_users table

Tags: database, wordpress

wp_users is creating users but without an ID in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your settings for ID looks like this in MySql and ensure AUTO_INCREMENT is ticked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you create `wp_users` manually?  The `ID` column should be defined as `auto_increment` by default; extracting from one of my databases shows:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Try altering the column as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/mysql-alter-a-column-to-be-auto-increment).

Might be worth checking that the other tables have the correct structure as well (auto_increment, indices, etc).  The correct definitions can be found in [schema.php, here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/schema.php#L22).

Answer (score 0):

It is ***auto incremented***.

No need to define when you **create the users**.

for the more info, please visit the wordpress.com for any help.