# What's the code in turning an ID into an autonumber data type?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I am using a visual studio 2010 and Microsoft SQ'L Server 2005.

I want my text box Equip_No to be an auto number data type.

I already followed these steps

```
Set the properties:

Identity Specification = Yes
(Is Identity) = Yes
Identity Increment = 1
Identity Seed = 1
```

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In what way do those steps not work?

Comment: I already tried it but my text box isn't showing any default value. I want it to have a default value whenever I run it or after I add a data to the database.

Comment: Do you have SQL access, or do you have to use VS2010 code to do this? You could employ this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/mysql-alter-a-column-to-be-auto-increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can alter an existing column into identity in Sqlserver-2005.

You can however add a column with identity and after that manipulate the values and change the seed

Adding the autoincremental column

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable 
ADD newid INT identity(1,1)
```

Making it possible to change your values in your id column however you want

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourtable ON
```

Do your manipulating here, example:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET newid = id
```

Cleanup

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourtable OFF

DBCC CHECKIDENT
 ('YourTable', RESEED, <a value at least 1 higher than the max existing value>);
```

Replacing old column

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP COLUMN id
SP_RENAME 'yourtable.newid', 'id', 'COLUMN'
```