# Error changing MySQL column to AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

Here is my current table design:

[image]

I have several columns and no KEYs set, so when I try the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment;
```

it gives me an error. I want the id column in the table to auto-increment and I want it to start with 1.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: what error exactly does it give you?

Comment: how about `alter table users change id id int primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: @Nordenheim In SQL Fiddle the error returns `Schema Creation Failed: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key:`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the primary key definition. Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Also, I recommend you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/mysql-alter-a-column-to-be-auto-increment) out.

Comment: Good answer. This should work. I think it's also important to mention that the reason this is required is because a column *CANNOT* be auto_increment if it is not a Primary Key. In OP's case, id is not a key, so that is why it cannot be altered to auto_increment alone.

Comment: Also, a funny thing to note (since you asked in the comments) I believe the error OP is getting is this: `Schema Creation Failed: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key: `

Answer (score 0):

You must specify `PRIMARY_KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY id INT PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```