# MySQL: AUTO_INCREMENT with PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment, mysql-error-1068

I've done a little research on this in the past hour, and I could use some help understanding some things.

Why doesn't this work? Got the basis for it from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/mysql-alter-a-column-to-be-auto-increment)

```
ALTER TABLE customers
MODIFY COLUMN customer_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

When I attempt to run it, I receive the error: **Multiple primary key defined.**

It works when I take out PRIMARY KEY, but is it still doing what I need it to do? (which is increment the customer_id, which is a PK, by 1.)

The customer_id is a primary key, does marking it as a primary key make it think that there are two?

Another question, when you use AUTO_INCREMENT without declaring how many it increments by, what is the default value to increment, 1?

Comment: I assume you mean to say that `customer_id` was already the primary key before this `MODIFY`? If so, yes, your auto increment will be working correctly. If you look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers`, you should see both the PK and auto_increment in `customer_id`.

Comment: MySQL will not permit adding auto_increment on a column which is not a primary key.

Comment: You probably has one or more primary keys in this table. You can certainly add more then 1 primary keys to the table, but you should do it at once. Drop any pk first, the try again.  Autoincrement value is 1.