# Mysql autoincrement does not increment

Tags: mysql, null, auto-increment, default-value

I have this table:

`mysql> desc Customers;`

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CustomerID | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name       | char(50)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Address    | char(100)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| City       | char(30)         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now, If I want to insert sample data:

```
mysql> insert into Customers values(null, 'Julia Smith', '25 Oak Street', 'Airport West');
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'CustomerID' cannot be null
```

I know I cannot make the ID null, but that should be job of mysql to set it numbers and increment them. So I try to simple not specifying the id:

```
mysql> insert into Customers (Name, Address, City) values('Julia Smith', '25 Oak Street', 'Airport West');
Field 'CustomerID' doesn't have a default value
```

Now I am in trap. I cannot make id null (which is saying for mysql "increment my ID"), and I cannot omit it, becuase there is no default value. So how should I make mysql to handle ids for me in new insertions?

Comment: What does your `CREATE TABLE` query look like? *It is the job of MySQL to increment the number* only for a field that is set to be `auto_increment`. If your `CustomerID` was `auto_increment` you'd see it in the `Extra` column.

Comment: Your field has no `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alter a MySQL column to be AUTO\_INCREMENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169080/alter-a-mysql-column-to-be-auto-increment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary key means that every CustomerID  has to be unique. and you defined it also as NOT NULL, so that an INSERT of NULL is not permitted

instead of >| CustomerID | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |

Make it

```
CustomerID  BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

and you can enter your data without problem

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY CustomerID BIGINT  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

@Milan,

Delete the CustomerID var from the table. And add this field again with the following details:

Field: CustomerID,
Type: BIGINT(10),
Default: None,
Auto_increment: tick in the checkbox

Click SAVE button to save this new field in the table. Now I hopefully it will work while inserting the new record. Thanks.